# existence and uniqueness for semilinear heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Consider a semilinear heat equation on $[0,1]$
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+b(t,x,u(t,x)).
$$
We assume here the periodic boundary conditions, that is $u(0,t)=u(1,t)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(1,t)$.

Suppose that the function $b$ is nice i.e that it is smooth in all arguments and some growth condition holds

$$y b(t,x,y)\le C_1+C_2y^2.$$

How can we prove that this equation has a unique solution? I couldn't find an appropriate theorem in Evans' book, but maybe I should look somewhere else?

Comment: you use the method of eigenfunction expansion twice I believe

Comment: @RyanHowe Could you please provide some more details? Or maybe there is a reference, where I can find about it? The point is I do not need to construct the solution, rather just to prove that it exists and unique.

Comment: it's apparently called gronwells inequality

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6.pdf it's on page 14

Comment: I think the other theorem is picard lindelof  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: @RyanHowe thanks for the link. However the theorem there establishes only the existence/uniqueness of weak solutions. Do you know any results about the strong solutions?